# Verificar se uma lista contém os elementos de outra lista ao longo das linhas de um dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ciência-de-dados, ipython-notebook

Tenho o seguinte data frame:

[image: Exemplo]

As colunas 2 e 5 contém listas em seus conteúdos, preciso verificar ao longo do dataframe, se os items presentes na lista da coluna 5 estão presentes na lista da coluna 2.

Tentei assim: `cursos_por_nome['Em dia'] = cursos_por_nome['Cursos Obrigatorios'].apply(lambda x: "Sim" if all(x) in cursos_por_nome['ID da Ação Educacional'] else "Nao")`, porém todos resultados deram 'não', sendo que já fiz teste de mesa e era pra alguns darem 'sim'.

Comment: `em_dia_1 = [] \n

for i in cursos_por_nome.itertuples(): \n
    result =  all(elem in i._2 for elem in i._5)\n  
    if result:
        em_dia_1.append('Sim')
    else:
        em_dia_1.append('Não')`

Resolvi assim

Answer (score 1):

Tendo este como dataframe de teste:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8]], "B": [[3,4], [5,6], [7,8,9]]})

df
           A          B
0  [1, 2, 3]     [3, 4]
1  [4, 5, 6]     [5, 6]
2     [7, 8]  [7, 8, 9]
```

Acredito que a solução abaixo traria uma performance melhor:

```
list(map(lambda a, b: "Sim" if len(set(a).intersection(b)) == len(a) else "Nao", df['A'], df['B']))

['Nao', 'Nao', 'Sim']
```

Answer (score -1):

Resolvi desta forma:

```
em_dia_1 = []

for i in cursos_por_nome.itertuples():
    result =  all(elem in i._2 for elem in i._5)

    if result:
      em_dia_1.append('Sim')
    else:
      em_dia_1.append('Não')
```